# Cordova SQLite plugin promises javascript chain

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

Hello guys so I'm trying to call 3 promises in one iteration then after they are done iterate one more time and call them one more time. Can anyone help me to solve this?

```
for(i=0;i<$scope.CurrentES.Issues.length;i++){
    app.Logger($scope.CurrentES.Issues[i])
    var promiseEvidence = $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, queryEvidence, [$scope.CurrentES.Issues[i].Evidence.Id]).then(function(result){
    app.Logger(result.rows.item(0).ImageID);
    app.Logger(result.rows.item(0).SupportingDocumetID);
    app.Logger(result.rows.item(0).QuoteID);
    var promiseImageLib = $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, queryImgLib, [result.rows.item(0).ImageID]).then(
        function (r) {
            if (r.rows.length != 0) {
                var img = r.rows.item(0);
                issue.Evidence.ImageLibary.Id = img.id;
                issue.Evidence.ImageLibary.ServerID = img.ServerID;
                issue.Evidence.ImageLibary.Conclude = img.Conclusion;
                issue.Evidence.ImageLibary.ImageTitle = img.Title;
                issue.Evidence.ImageLibary.Image = img.Image;
            }
        }, function (e) {
            app.Logger(e);
        });
        var promiseSupp = $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, querySupp, [result.rows.item(0).SupportingDocumetID]).then(
            function (r) {
                if (r.rows.length != 0) {
                    var sup = r.rows.item(0);
                    issue.Evidence.SupportingDocument.Id = sup.id;
                    issue.Evidence.SupportingDocument.ServerID = sup.ServerID;
                    issue.Evidence.SupportingDocument.Link = sup.Link;
                    issue.Evidence.SupportingDocument.Title = sup.Title;
                    issue.Evidence.SupportingDocument.Quoatation = sup.Extract;
                }
            }, function (e) {
                app.Logger(e);
            });
            var promiseQuote = $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, quesryQuote, [result.rows.item(0).QuoteID]).then(
                function (r) {
                    if (r.rows.length != 0) {
                        var quot = r.rows.item(0);
                        issue.Evidence.Quote.Id = quot.id;
                        issue.Evidence.Quote.ServerID = quot.ServerID;
                        issue.Evidence.Quote.Quoatation = quot.QuoteLegend;
                        issue.Evidence.Quote.Attributed = quot.QuoteText;
                    }
                }, function (e) {
                    app.Logger(e);
                });
                $q.all([promiseImageLib,promiseSupp,promiseQuote]).then(function(r){
            })
        });
        var isDone = $q.all([promiseEvidence]).then(function(r){

    })
}
```

Comment: Can you be more clear in your question? You are iterating an unknown number of times based on Issues.length. And then you want what to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to think about this is that the construction of your promise chain is independent of their execution. Once you get that mental model in place, it's easy to reason about.

Let's break it down into steps and build up our code from there.

**Execute asynchronous code and allow actions to happen after they are done:**

```
function doSomeAsyncWork(){
   var promise1 = foo();
   var promise2 = bar();
   var promise3 = blah();

   return $q.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]);
}
```

**Repeat this code N number of times, but sequentially. After the first iteration has run.**

```
function doWorkNTimes(n) {
 var lastPromise;

 for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     //After initial promise, keep
     // chaining them together
     if (lastPromise) {
       lastPromise = lastPromise.then(function(items) {
         return doStuffAsync(i);
       });
     } else {
       lastPromise = doStuffAsync(i);
     }
 }

 return lastPromise;
};
```

Here is a working example that is slightly more sophisticated, but should demonstrate the point.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  }

  function promiseController($q, $timeout) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.results = [];

    vm.numTimes = 3;

    vm.isBusy = false;

    vm.isDone = true;

    vm.doWork = function(times) {
      vm.results.splice(0);
      vm.isBusy = true;
      vm.isDone = false;

      doWorkNTimes(vm.numTimes || 1)
        .finally(function() {
          vm.isBusy = false;
          vm.isDone = true;
        });
    };

    function doWorkNTimes(n) {
      var lastPromise;

      for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        (function(i) {
          if (lastPromise) {
            lastPromise = lastPromise.then(function(items) {
              return doStuffAsync(i);
            });
          } else {
            lastPromise = doStuffAsync(i);
          }

          lastPromise.then(function(items) {
            //console.log(items);

            vm.results.push(items);
          });
        }(i));
      }

      return lastPromise;
    };

    function doStuffAsync(i) {
      var prom1 = createPromise(i),
        prom2 = createPromise(i),
        prom3 = createPromise(i);

      return $q.all([prom1, prom2, prom3]);
    }

    function createPromise(i) {
      var timeout = getRandomInt(200, 2000);

      return $timeout(function() {

        var item = {
          iteration: i,
          executionTime: timeout
        };

        //console.log(item);

        return item;

      }, timeout);
    }
  }

  angular.module('promise-sample', [])
    .controller('promiseController', promiseController);

}());
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" ng-app="promise-sample" ng-controller="promiseController as ctrl">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Number of Iterations</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" min="0" max="10" ng-model="ctrl.numTimes" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ctrl.doWork()">Run {{ctrl.numTimes}} Times</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <table class="table table-striped" ng-repeat="set in ctrl.results">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Run</th>
            <th>Time</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="item in set">
            <td>{{::item.iteration}}</td>
            <td>{{::item.executionTime}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm could you simplify this somehow im not javascript ninja ; ) And have some problem reading this ;)

http://www.codeshare.io/QBtHg lets say how to make this in this case its mile stone for me this javascript promises;)

Comment: @Alex - I'm not sure how much simpler I can make the answer given what you are trying to accomplish. Is there a particular part that is more confusing than the rest? I can do my best to explain.

Comment: why u are using something like (function(){})  it means something?

Comment: Ah... The outer one is called an Immediately Invoked Function Expression or **IIFE** for short. It keeps the global scope from being polluted and avoids naming collisions. The one inside the for loop is to capture the current value of `i`. JavaScript has only function level scope and so without that, the value of `i` would be subject to change. The function creates a new scope and therefore preserves the **current** value.

Comment: Could you have a look on my sharecode and tell me how can i do this in yours way because i see its working but ill try to do it too  ! Hard to move from c# to javascript... but my client need this ...

Comment: Sure thing. Yeah, I am also a C# dev, but it has taken me a while to get up to speed on all the nuances of JS. As a side note, you should look into TypeScript.

Comment: Ye know that but to look i need some time ;) and this is low atm!;)

Comment: Thanks for your help it helped me to understand the promises;)